# How to use reduce to find maximum from array of objects with array of objects

Tags: javascript, reduce

If I have the following

```
arr = [
{key: "a",
values : [{key: "aa", value: 2}, {key: "bb", value: 5}]},
{key: "b",
values : [{key: "cc", value: 7}, {key: "dd", value: 3}]}
]
```

How to use `reduce` in javascript to find the maximum from the nested objects? The answer should be 7 in the above case.

I currently am able to use a loop to achieve this:

```js
let max = 0;
let findDataMax = function(d) {
  for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    let currArr = d[i].values;
    let tempArr = []
    currArr.forEach((d) => tempArr.push(+d.value));
    if (Math.max(...tempArr) > max) {
      max = Math.max(...tempArr);
    }
  }
}

let arr = [
  {key: "a", values : [{key: "aa", value: 2}, {key: "bb", value: 5}]},
  {key: "b",values : [{key: "cc", value: 7}, {key: "dd", value: 3}]}
];
findDataMax(arr);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Do you have to use reduce for this?

Comment: Yes, i do if it can be done. else i was able to loop over all and find the maximum.

Comment: Can you please show your loop approach / what you've tried so far?

Comment: Could you show expected output as well?

Comment: this finds the max of one element. If i loop over one more time i can find the global maxima. this code finds the local maxima
```let max = 0;
let findDataMax = function (d) {
    for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        let currArr = d[i].values;
        let tempArr = []
        currArr.forEach((d) => tempArr.push(+d.value));
        if (Math.max(...tempArr) > max) {
            max = Math.max(...tempArr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and the formatting turned out bad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use other methods other than reduce for this, but if you have to, then you can set the accumulator as `-Infinity` to begin with (this way any value compared with the accumulator will be bigger than `-Infinity`). For each object in your array, you can find the max by mapping the array of `values` to an array of `value` numbers from each object, and then [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) these numbers into a call to [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). You can then compare whether or not this is larger than the current maximum, and if it is, return that as the new value to use as the accumulator, otherwise, use the old accumulator value:

```js
const arr = [ {key: "a", values : [{ key: "aa", value: 2}, { key: "bb",value: 5}]}, {key: "b", values : [{ key: "cc", value: 7}, { key: "dd", value: 3}]} ];

const max = arr.reduce((max, {values}) => {
  const newMax = Math.max(...values.map(({value}) => value));
  return newMax > max ? newMax : max;
}, -Infinity);
console.log(max);
```

As previously mentioned, I would probably use a different approach to `.reduce()`, such as [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to grab all object `value` numbers, which you can then spread into a call to `Math.max()`:

```js
const arr = [ {key: "a", values : [{ key: "aa", value: 2}, { key: "bb",value: 5}]}, {key: "b", values : [{ key: "cc", value: 7}, { key: "dd", value: 3}]} ];

const max = Math.max(...arr.flatMap(({values}) => values.map(({value}) => value)));
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the use of the `reduce` function is a clean solution for this problem but here you have it:

```js
const arr = [{ key: 'a', values: [{ key: 'aa', value: 2 }, { key: 'bb', value: 5 }] }, { key: 'b', values: [{ key: 'cc', value: 7 }, { key: 'dd', value: 3 }] }];

// O(n * b)
const maxValue = arr.reduce((prev, item) => item
  .values.reduce((subPrev, subItem) => (subItem.value > subPrev ? subItem.value : subPrev), prev), 0);

console.log(maxValue); //  7
```